# sorting lists in python 3

Tags: python, list, defaultdict

So, I need to sort this kind of list with some random data in it by first `element` of second nested list (with elements like `01, 02, 03`, etc):

```
  [['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00553', ['02', '2.1']], ['00551', ['02', '5.3']], etc]
```

this random data is later used in defaultdict with some other data, in order to group it together and print it out by key (the keys are numbers like `00553, 00551`).

I tried to sort it before putting it to defaultdict but all I am getting sorted out is values of nested list itself..

can anybody please help me, I am new in this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lis = [['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00553', ['02', '2.1']],
      ['00551', ['02', '5.3']], ['00551', ['01', '5.3']],['00551', ['04', '5.3']]]
import operator
newlist = sorted(lis, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

result

```
>>> newlist
[['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00551', ['01', '5.3']], 
      ['00553', ['02', '2.1']], ['00551', ['02', '5.3']], ['00551', ['04', '5.3']]]
```

Comment: Shadowing `sorted` is awesome!

Comment: no, shadowing built-ins isn't awesome at all; it's an error-prone practice that should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> lis = [['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00553', ['02', '2.1']], ['00551', ['02', '5.3']]]
>>> sorted(lis, key = lambda x: int(x[1][0])) 
[['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00553', ['02', '2.1']], ['00551', ['02', '5.3']]]
```

Comment: Why do love lists more than anything? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like `lambda` but a bit of documentation:

```
L = [['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00553', ['02', '2.1']], ['00551', ['02', '5.3']]]
def by_first_of_second(sub_list):
    """First element of second entry as sort key.
       Convert to int to sort by numerical value.
    """
    return int(sub_list[1][0])

sorted(L, key=by_first_of_second)
```

Result:

```
[['00553', ['01', '3.4']], ['00553', ['02', '2.1']], ['00551', ['02', '5.3']]]
```