# Python 3 Sorting a List of Tuples?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am a Python newbie and I have a question. I was told to ask this separately from another post I made for the same program. This is homework, so I would just like some guidance. I have a list of tuples, and I want to sort it by tuple[0] and return the full tuple for use in printing to the screen. The tuples are made up of (score,mark(x or o),index)

Here is my basic code (part of a tic tac toe game- I have the full code in another post):::

```
listOfScores = miniMax(gameBoard)
best = max(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])

if best[0] == 0:
            print("You should mark " + best[1] + " in cell " + best[2] + ".")
            print("This will lead to a tie.")
        elif best[0] > 0:
            print("You should mark " + best[1] + " in cell " + best[2] + ".")
            print("This will lead to a win.")
        else:
            print("You should mark " + best[1] + " in cell " + best[2] + ".")
            print("This will lead to a loss.")
```

I am getting this error:::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\CS 3610\hw2\hw2Copy.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Abby\Desktop\CS 3610\hw2\hw2Copy.py", line 120, in main
    best = max(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. This is my first time trying to use this:

```
best = max(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

so I think that maybe I am using it incorrectly. Is there a better way to sort these tuples (from largest to smallest, and smallest to largest), so that I can retrieve either the smallest or largest value? Thank you! :)

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value

Answer (score 10):

If you want to *sort* it, then use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) ;)

```
best = sorted(listOfScores, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

This will sort it from the lowest score to the highest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

```
listOfScores = [1, 3, 2]
```

This is how its done:

```
best = max(listOfScores, key=lambda x:x)
```

It's not lambda x:x[0]. That would apply for a case like :

```
listOfScores = [[1], [3], [2]]
```

Hope this helps.