# Capital letter word count python

Tags: python, structure

Right now my code prints how many times every word is used in the txt file. I'm trying to get it to ONLY print the top 3 words used with capital letters within the txt file...

```
file=open("novel.txt","r+")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
for a,b in wordcount.items():
    print (b, a)
```

Comment: [`str.istitle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.istitle) or [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to limit your result to only capitalized words using [`str.istitle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.istitle):

```
file=open("novel.txt","r+")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word.istitle():
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
for a,b in wordcount.items():
    print (b, a)
```

Then [sort the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720975/python-3-sorting-a-list-of-tuples) using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and print out the first three:

```
file=open("novel.txt","r+")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word.istitle():
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1

items = sorted(wordcount.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True) 

for item in items[:3]:
    print item[0], item[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! it is working to sort the capital letters but still producing an error...6 Jellicle
5 Cats
2 And
1 They
1 Moon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 13, in <module>
    items.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True) 
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: @hendro3 The code would only work in Python 2. I've updated it to be Python 3 friendly.

Answer (score -1):

In `Collections` there's a `Counter` class. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html.

```
cnt = Counter([w for w in file.read().split() if w.lower() != w]).most_common(3)
```

Comment: He wants to have only the ones with capital letters, I suggest you to change `file.read().split()` to [w for w in file.read().split() if w.istitle()]`

Comment: Thank you Jose! Yes I am trying to read the text file and print the top 3 words used that are in capital letter

Comment: `[w for w in file.read().split() if w.istitle()]` seems concise to a fault for a beginner... probably better just to loop through everything and use `if word.istitle():`. I don't think there's a performance or readability benefit to the list comprehension.

Comment: Well I can read `[w for w in file.read().split() if w.istitle()]` as "word for each word in the file that I read and split in words only if word is title". I think is more concise more readable and much more simpler. I mean, he just wants to count, if he wants to implement a counter then he can look at the [standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py) or ask Raymond Hettinger. If it is a simple thing to tell then it MUST be a simple thing to code (in python).