# sort a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list of tuples "degree"

> [('WA', 2), ('DE', 3), ('DC', 2), ('WI', 4), ('WV', 5), ('FL', 2), ('WY', 6), ('NH', 3), ('NJ', 3), ('NM', 4), ('TX', 4), ('LA', 3), ('NC', 4), ('ND', 3), ('NE', 6), ('TN', 8), ('NY', 5), ('PA', 6), ('RI', 2), ('NV', 5), ('VA', 6), ('CO', 6), ('CA', 3), ('AL', 4), ('AR', 6), ('VT', 3), ('IL', 5), ('GA', 5), ('IN', 4), ('IA', 6), ('MA', 5), ('AZ', 4), ('ID', 6), ('CT', 3), ('ME', 1), ('MD', 5), ('OK', 6), ('OH', 5), ('UT', 5), ('MO', 8), ('MN', 4), ('MI', 3), ('KS', 4), ('MT', 4), ('MS', 4), ('SC', 2), ('KY', 7), ('OR', 4), ('SD', 6)]

I want to sort the tuple from lowest to highest (by number, not by state) so lt looks like :

```
[('ME', 1),....,('MO', 8)]
```

I tried this but it does not work, how can i fix it?

```
print sorted(degree)
```

Comment: @Amith Please do not use backticks for anything except code, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value)

Comment: This is exact duplicate. Why don't you ask Google first? https://www.google.ru/search?q=sort+list+of+tuples+by+second+element+python

Comment: Even ans posted below are duplicate..:-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
sorted(degree, key=lambda (k,v): v)
```

Comment: Nope. Should be `lambda (k,v): v`

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(degree, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) which will return a new *sorted* list. We are passing an optional argument, `key`. Here, we are using a `lambda` function. `sorted()` will base its result in the function passed, which will evaluate each element. For example, for the first element:

```
('WA', 2)   # x
```

the function will return `x[1]`. In other words, `2`. Similarly for other elements.

```
print sorted(degree, key = lambda x : x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def comp(x,y):
    return x[1] - y[1]

degree.sort(comp)
```