# Sorting a list of tuples by their second element, which is a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have got the hang of sorting a list of tuples by their second elements when that element is just a solo integer, but something about the second elements being lists of integers is throwing me. for example with the following list...

```
[("Jack", [1,2,5,3]), ("Anna", [7,8,5,2]), ("Ryan", [1,2,1,1])]
```

... I am trying to sort the list of tuples into ascending order based on the sums of the lists within each (so as to produce the following outcome in this example)...

```
[("Ryan", [1,2,1,1]), ("Jack", [1,2,5,3]), ("Anna", [7,8,5,2])]
```

Thanks

*edit*: My question differs from [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value) because mine refers specifically to the case in which the second element is a list, which is where my stumbling block was. Thanks for helpful replies so far.

Comment: did any of the below answer your question if not comment on them

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`key`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda) attribute of the sort function

**Code:**

```
check = [("Jack", [1, 2, 5, 3]), ("Anna", [7, 8, 5, 2]), ("Ryan", [1, 2, 1, 1])]
sorted(check, key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Ryan', [1, 2, 1, 1]), ('Jack', [1, 2, 5, 3]), ('Anna', [7, 8, 5, 2])]
```

**Notes:**

- First I created a list check
- The sorted function is used to create a sorted list
- The `key` attribute is passed with `sum` to sort by the sum of the `list` in the tuple

For a more robust method you could use the below method

**Code1:**

```
check = [("Jack", [1, 2, 5, 3]), ("Anna", [7, 8, 5, 2]), ("Ryan", [1, 2, 1, 1])]
def validator(lst):
    if isinstance(lst,list):
        return sum(lst)
    else:
        return lst
print sorted(check, key=lambda x: validator(x[1]))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Bad', 2), ('Ryan', [1, 2, 1, 1]), ('Jack', [1, 2, 5, 3]), ('Anna', [7, 8, 5, 2])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a function to `key` in `sorted`:

```
L = [("Jack", [1,2,5,3]), ("Anna", [7,8,5,2]), ("Ryan", [1,2,1,1])]
sorted(L, key=lambda x: sum(x[1])) 
[('Ryan', [1, 2, 1, 1]), ('Jack', [1, 2, 5, 3]), ('Anna', [7, 8, 5, 2])]
```

This `func = lambda x: sum(x[1])` is equivalent to:

```
def func(x):
    return sum(x[1])
```

Now you can use `func` instead of the lambda expression:

```
sorted(L, key=func)
```

The return value of this function, i.e. the sum of the second element in the tuple will be used as sorting criterion.