# Pythonic way to sort on tuple, dict item and convert to array

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

Given this array of tuple

```
[('h1', 0.522611856461), ('h2', 0.438368797302), ('h3', 0.443703174591)]
```

Or given this dictionary

```
{'h2': 0.438368797302, 'h3': 0.443703174591, 'h1': 0.522611856461}
```

How can I create an array of the 'h' items `['h2', 'h3', 'h1']` which is sorted by the float item?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [('h1', 0.522611856461), ('h2', 0.438368797302), ('h3', 0.443703174591)]
>>> [x[0] for x in sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))]
['h2', 'h3', 'h1']
```