# Formulate query and rank answers via cosine similarity Python

Tags: python, jupyter, cosine-similarity

I tokenized multiple text files and created a `tf-idf` matrix from that:

```
Token 1 Token 2 Token 3
Doc 1  0.00..   0.0002  0.0003
Doc 2  0.00..   ...     ...
Doc 3  ...      ...     ...
...
```

How do I now formulate a query, say for token 1 and token 3?

How do I then rank them using cosine similarity?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to rank them per Doc I suggest using a tuple per Token. I'm not certain on the maths behind cosine similarity but assuming we can use a function `f(x,y)` that returns the cosine similarity between x and y, we can apply this to Token 1 to Token 2 and 3 as per your suggestion as follows:

```
list_with_scores = []
for i,doc in enumerate(Docs):
    score1_3 = f(doc[0],doc[1])
    score1_3 = f(doc[0],doc[2])
    list_with_scores.append(i,score1_3, score_2_3,)
#then sort by score1_3
sortedlist1 = sorted(list_with_scores, key = lambda x:x[1])
#similary, sort by score2_3
sortedlist2 = sorted(list_with_scores, key = lambda x:x[2])
```

You can also keep the token score in the tuple if required. And the explicit saving to `score1_3` and `score1_2` can be removed, it's done for readiblity, probably better to leave them as is. For more information regarding the sorting part, check [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value)