# How to reorganize a list of tuples?

Tags: python, hashtable

Say I had a list of tuples:

```
[(98, 'studentA'), (97, 'studentB'), (98, 'studentC'), (95,'studentD')]
```

And I wanted to organize it so that the students are grouped together by the first number in the tuple, what would be the best approach?

I was thinking about creating an array of lists, in which each index of the array would be a different score (98, 97, and 95 in this example) and the students would be in the list at that index. For a much larger dataset I was considering creating a chaining hash table, but I wasn't sure what to % it to, to guarantee that two scores that aren't the same won't get hashed to the same spot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value)

Comment: Probably the simplest way would just be to fold the list into a dictionary, where the key is the score. The indexing idea would work, but then you have a unnecessarily huge array where most of the elements are `None`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a `dict`?  `collections.defaultdict` would work too:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for score, student in l:
    d[score] += student
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sorted with a key of the number

```
sorted(students, key=(lambda x: x[0]))
```

But a dictionary would be a better idea for a large dataset