# Loop through dict's inner list, add missing month

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been struggling with how to loop through a list, adding 0 for the missing months back in to the original dictionary.  I am thinking to create a list of months, from `calendar`, loop through each of those, then loop through each month in my data...but can't quite figure out how to update the dictionary when there's a missing month in correct order.

```
import calendar

my_dict = {'Green Car': 
        [('January', 340), 
        ('February', 2589), 
        ('March', 12750), 
        ('April', 114470), 
        ('July', 4935),
        ('August', 1632),
        ('September', 61),
        ('December', 3409)], 
    'Red Truck': 
        [('January', 2325185), 
        ('February', 209794), 
        ('March', 201874),
        ('April', 19291),
        ('May', 18705), 
        ('July', 22697), 
        ('August', 22796)], 
    'Police Car': 
        [('January', 2037), 
        ('February', 2620), 
        ('March', 1480), 
        ('April', 15630), 
        ('July', 40693), 
        ('August', 2329)], 
    'Zamboni': 
        [('January', 256), 
        ('February', 426690), 
        ('March', 589), 
        ('April', 4740), 
        ('May', 880), 
        ('July', 1016), 
        ('August', 106), 
        ('September', 539), 
        ('October', 598), 
        ('November', 539), 
        ('December', 470)], 
    'Witch Broom': 
        [('February', 350),
        ('March', 3520), 
        ('October', 2703), 
        ('November', 2221), 
        ('December', 664)]
    }


def fill_months(reported_months):
    const_months = list(calendar.month_name)
    x = 0
    print("Looking for months in", reported_months) 
    # print(const_months)
    for const_month in const_months:
        for month in reported_months:
            if const_month != month[0] and len(const_month) > 0:
                print(const_month, month[0])
                print("You don't have", const_month, "in the months group:", reported_months)


def main():
    for commod, months in my_dict.items():
        # print(commod)
        # print(commod, months)
        fill_months(months)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For each key ("Green Car", "Red Truck", etc.) I want to loop through and add in a missing moth with the value `0`.  So the "Green Car" in the end would turn out to be:

```
my_dict = {'Green Car': 
        [('January', 340), 
        ('February', 2589), 
        ('March', 12750), 
        ('April', 114470),
        ('May', 0),
        ('June', 0),
        ('July', 4935),
        ('August', 1632),
        ('September', 61),
        ('October', 0),
        ('November', 0),
        ('December', 3409)],
```

---

I'm getting somewhere with this - but the logic feels kind of kludgy:

```
def fill_months(reported_months):
    const_months = list(calendar.month_name)
    x = 0
    temp_months = []
    for i in reported_months:
        temp_months.append(i[0])
    print("Looking for months in", reported_months) 
    # print(const_months)
    for const_month in const_months:
        if len(const_month) > 0:
            if const_month not in temp_months:
                reported_months.insert(x-1, (const_month, 0))
        x += 1
    print(reported_months)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that the logic adding missing months has to check for is if months don't match by index to some list of month names you have, `months`. Increment if they do match, and loop until every member of `months` is covered.

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
          'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def add_missing_months(vehicle_d):    
    for vehicle in vehicle_d:
        ind = 0
        month_l = vehicle_d[vehicle]
        while ind < len(months):
            if ind >= len(month_l) or month_l[ind][0] != months[ind]:
                month_l.insert(ind, (months[ind], 0))
            else:
                ind += 1
    return vehicle_d
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add the months to your list and then sort the monthlists

```
# remove the leading empty '' from calendar.month_name list
monthnames = [x for x in calendar.month_name if x != ''] 

# scan dicts for missing monts, if found, append tuple (monthname,0) to list
for part in my_dict:
    print(part)
    for month in monthnames:
        if not month in [x[0] for x in my_dict[part]]:
            my_dict[part].append( (month,0) ) 

# modified https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value
# interrate through dict, assign sorted dict, use indexlookup into monthlist for sorting
for part in my_dict:
    my_dict[part] = sorted(my_dict[part], key=lambda x: monthnames.index(x[0]))

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Red Truck'
    : [('January', 2325185)
        ,( 'February', 209794)
        ,( 'March', 201874)
        ,( 'April', 19291)
        ,( 'May', 18705)
        ,( 'June', 0)
        ,( 'July', 22697)
        ,( 'August', 22796)
        ,( 'September', 0)
        ,( 'October', 0)
        ,( 'November', 0)
        ,( 'December', 0)], 
'Witch Broom'
    : [('January', 0)
        ,( 'February', 350)
        ,( 'March', 3520)
        ,( 'April', 0)
        ,( 'May', 0)
        ,( 'June', 0)
        ,( 'July', 0)
        ,( 'August', 0)
        ,( 'September', 0)
        ,( 'October', 2703)
        ,( 'November', 2221)
        ,( 'December', 664)], 
'Police Car'
    : [('January', 2037)
        ,( 'February', 2620)
        ,( 'March', 1480)
        ,( 'April', 15630)
        ,( 'May', 0)
        ,( 'June', 0)
        ,( 'July', 40693)
        ,( 'August', 2329)
        ,( 'September', 0)
        ,( 'October', 0)
        ,( 'November', 0)
        ,( 'December', 0)], 
'Green Car'
    : [('January', 340)
        ,( 'February', 2589)
        ,( 'March', 12750)
        ,( 'April', 114470)
        ,( 'May', 0)
        ,( 'June', 0)
        ,( 'July', 4935)
        ,( 'August', 1632)
        ,( 'September', 61)
        ,( 'October', 0)
        ,( 'November', 0)
        ,( 'December', 3409)], 
'Zamboni'
    : [('January', 256)
        ,( 'February', 426690)
        ,( 'March', 589)
        ,( 'April', 4740)
        ,( 'May', 880)
        ,( 'June', 0)
        ,( 'July', 1016)
        ,( 'August', 106)
        ,( 'September', 539)
        ,( 'October', 598)
        ,( 'November', 539)
        ,( 'December', 470)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sets` difference to get which months are missing in your `reported_month` and then add them with 0 to your list.

filter with bool is used to remove empty string from the list.

```
import calendar


my_dict = {
'Green Car':
        [('January', 340),
        ('February', 2589),
        ('March', 12750),
        ('April', 114470),
        ('July', 4935),
        ('August', 1632),
        ('September', 61),
        ('December', 3409)],
    'Red Truck':
        [('January', 2325185),
        ('February', 209794),
        ('March', 201874),
        ('April', 19291),
        ('May', 18705),
        ('July', 22697),
        ('August', 22796)],
    'Police Car':
        [('January', 2037),
        ('February', 2620),
        ('March', 1480),
        ('April', 15630),
        ('July', 40693),
        ('August', 2329)],
    'Zamboni':
        [('January', 256),
        ('February', 426690),
        ('March', 589),
        ('April', 4740),
        ('May', 880),
        ('July', 1016),
        ('August', 106),
        ('September', 539),
        ('October', 598),
        ('November', 539),
        ('December', 470)],
    'Witch Broom':
        [('February', 350),
        ('March', 3520),
        ('October', 2703),
        ('November', 2221),
        ('December', 664)]
    }


def filter_month(x, months):
    """filters the month when month[i] == x
    """
    return [i[1] for i in months if i[0] == x][0]

def fill_months(reported_months):
    const_months = list(filter(bool, calendar.month_name))
    my_months = set(map(lambda x: x[0], reported_months))
    missing_months = set(const_months) - my_months

    for month in missing_months:
        reported_months.append((month, 0))

    # arranging
    arranged = list(map(lambda x: (x, filter_month(x, reported_months)), const_months))
    for i in range(len(reported_months)):
        reported_months[i] = arranged[i]

def main():
    for commod, months in my_dict.items():
        fill_months(months)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This works, although it adds the months to the end.  Is there a way to keep the sorting and insert the month where it should be chronologically?