# Sort nested list by another list

Tags: python

I have the following doubly-nested list:

```
records = [[['Jack', 'male', 1],['Jack', 'male', 2],['Jack', 'male', 3]],[['Sally', 'female', 1],['Sally', 'female', 2],['Sally', 'female', 3]]]
```

I want to sort this list according to this list...

```
list_order = ['female', 'male']
```

...such that the result is this:

```
records 
[[['Sally', 'female', 1],['Sally', 'female', 2],['Sally', 'female', 3]],[['Jack', 'male', 1],['Jack', 'male', 2],['Jack', 'male', 3]]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value This still applies to your lists

Comment: @Gigaflop agreed the strategy is basically the same, however I have a list of lists, rather than a list of tuples

Comment: Tuples and lists can be addressed in the same manner, like `(3, 4)[0]` is 3, and `[3, 4][0]` is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum`:

```
records = [[['Jack', 'male', 1],['Jack', 'male', 2],['Jack', 'male', 3]],[['Sally', 'female', 1],['Sally', 'female', 2],['Sally', 'female', 3]]]
list_order = ['female', 'male']
new_records = sorted(records, key=lambda x:sum(list_order.index(i[1]) for i in x))
```

Output:

```
[[['Sally', 'female', 1], ['Sally', 'female', 2], ['Sally', 'female', 3]], [['Jack', 'male', 1], ['Jack', 'male', 2], ['Jack', 'male', 3]]]
```

Comment: thanks, this works. can you explain what `sum` is doing?

Comment: @holastello `sum` creates a "score" of the number of times `"female"` or `"male"` occurs in each sublist. That way a value reflected the frequency of the target values can be used to determine a potential sorting swap.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit more complicated than what you are asking for. I am assuming:

1. You cannot guarantee that each group will contain only items from one "list_order" category
2. You want the final list to be doubly-nested, with all "list_order" categories grouped together
3. There is no ordering aside from the one column that matches "list_order"
4. Items should be in the EXACT order they are listed in "list_order"

So, you could use the following code:

```python
records = [[['Jack', 'male', 1],['Jack', 'male', 2],['Jack', 'male', 3]],[['Sally', 'female', 1],['Sally', 'female', 2],['Sally', 'female', 3]]]
list_order = ['female', 'male']

# "flatten" list into singly-nested list
records = [leaf for branch in records for leaf in branch]

# sort the items in the list by list_order 
# sorted passes each item in the list to the lambda function
# record[1] is the position of "male"/"female"
records = sorted(records, key=lambda record: list_order.index(record[1]))

# group the list by list_order again, creating doubly-nested list
records = [ [record for record in records if record[1] == item ] for item in list_order ]

print records
```

[Try it online (with debugging printouts)!](https://tio.run/##dVFBbsMgELz7FSvn4FRyWyW9VfIHeu3Rsqq1vSQoBCwgUv16dwGnpUpyAmZnd2aHafZHo/fLYmkwdnTQQNu21QcOp6qG6oyK@Nx19Q22v4O9dQy21ScqNQdYUD7gFt7fh3lMVyjp/BdbIhs8/RWTVlcUGyiFQu9JlxDIILU34KQ@qPlZk/M0RrzIVlOEAoSx0FvUw5Fb4FoNaCwzlqqsMVkeeqUESWesB38kkJ7OLnDDI8r3M2SeVy57mNA5ckAY9LjrXxM7jnc89yOCuOjBS6O5OWm2uw6ki5TJOBlqYASUIYPytUyhlMUm2zGpbleghhPNzTo@Ye@ZzRepR/re/oo9Pd3Z@WDNZXq0Jx5Q6hoGS@g5ehjNpX@cP7TpEdNer9kfSJHt3TQpri6Sr8ll0jf/syw/)