# Sorted key-value data store where keys are float and values are objects

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, key-value

I am trying to make a simple time-based script where the user inputs:

1. Time after starting the script to call an object, called `dt_call`

   - Generated by `time.perf_counter()` (aka it's a `float`)
2. Object to call at that time

Is there a Python library that has a key-value store that meets the following conditions?

1. Keys are `float`
2. Values are `object`
3. Keys are sorted

---

**More Information**

This will be part of a scheduler, where every so often the scheduler:

1. Gets the current time since starting the script (sec), called `dt`
2. Maybe call the object, depending on if it's call time has passed

   1. Looks to see `if dT >= dt_call`
   2. If yes: check if the associated object has been called.  If uncalled, then call the object.
   3. If no: do nothing

---

**Current Best Idea**

Currently, my best idea is based on this: [Sort a list of tuples by 2nd item (integer value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value)

Before starting the script:

1. Store `dt_call` + object pairs in a `tuple`
2. Store all pairs in a list
3. Sort using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44852626/11163122

```py
# Keys are `dt_call`
list_.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])

list_  # [(5.6, obj0), (5.9, obj1), (8.7, obj2)]
```

After starting the script:

1. Get `index` using `bisect.bisect`
2. See if object at `index - 1` was called.  If not, call it.

```py
# Start
start_time = time.perf_counter()

# Some time has passed
dt = time.perf_counter() - start_time

# Step 1
index = bisect.bisect([x[0] for x in list_], dt)

# Step 2
fetched_obj = list_[index - 1][1]
if fetched_obj.is_not_called():
    fetched_obj()
```

Is there a data structure I can use to accomplish this in a more direct manner (all in one)?

This idea combines multiple data structures to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mention needing a data structure which allows:

> ```
> Keys as floats
> Values are objects
> Sorting of Keys
> ```

Would suggest module
[Heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html)

Great for organizing items, which are list of tuples

> - tuple order controlled by elements in the tuple
> - objects can be values in the tuple
> - heap order is updated as items are added or deleted
> - Takes O(log(n)) in time to add or remove an item

Timer

```
from time import perf_counter
```

To use heap

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

heap = []   # any heap
```

Items are tuples

```
# delay from current time to perform action on object
scheduled_time = perf_counter() + delay
item = (scheduled_time , obji)  # i-th object
```

To add object to heap

```
heappush(heap, item)
```

Assuming heap as a list of items, to one is scheduled we have:

We process objects in the heap using the following loop

```
While True:

    # heap[0] is almost the smallest for a heap so
    scheduled_time, obj = heap[0]

    if perf_counter() >= schedule_time:
        # pop earliest off heap and do something
        heappop(heap)
        do_something(obj)
```

The heap automatically reorders the item with the earliest time upon heappop (remove and item) or heappush (add an item)

Comment: Thank you, yes it seems what I needed was a priority queue, and Python's `heapq` is a great implementation!  Thank you again!