# Linking several list and make it sorted python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have list:

```
productlinks = ['google.com', 'tes.com', 'lol.com']
name = ['google', 'tes', 'lol']
prices = ['$ 125.000,00', '$ 123.000,00','$ 135.000.000,00']
```

I want to linked each other and sorted it by the price, so when i sorted it would be look like this:

```
 productlinks = ['tes.com', 'google.com', 'lol.com']
 name = ['tes', 'google', 'lol']
 prices = ['$ 123.000,00', '$ 125.000,00','$ 135.000.000,00']
```

I have used zip function to merged it, but i dont know how to sort it by the price.

NOTE: the price in a string.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10695161/13238310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the list you get after zipping all three lists you can use this code,

```
import re

new_prices = list(map(lambda text: re.findall("\d+\.\d+", text)[0], prices))
final_list = list(zip(productlinks, name, new_prices))
sorted_list = pd.DataFrame(final_list).sort_values(by = 2).values
```

I have used the `pandas` module for the sorting part here.

The first line gets rid of all the **"**,**"** and **"**$**"** from the price and converts the rest into float. Then these new prices are `zipped` with the other two lists and the zipped output we get is then converted into a list.

Because `final_list` looks an awful lot like a table, I converted it into a `pandas` dataframe and sorted it by the column with the prices values. Now that the whole dataframe has been sorted, I convert it into an array using `.values`.

If you want to add **"**$**"** you can replace the third line with the code below,

```
sorted_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list).sort_values(by = 2)
sorted_df[2] = "$" + sorted_df[2].astype(str)
sorted_list = sorted_df.values
```

Comment: This is what works for me, but actually my prices is look like this: ["$ 13.000,00", "$ 12.000,00", $ 1.000,00"] and because of that there is errorValueError: could not convert string to float.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: It's almost solve the problem, but if there is data like $ 5.000.000,00 it will be error because there is 2 '.' and 1 ',' the error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 5.000.00000'

Comment: success with this new_prices = list(map(lambda price: int(price.replace('.', '').replace(',00', '').strip('$ ')), prices))
thank you for your help

Comment: but new answer is not sorted ya?

Comment: I think it still better previous answer + last added from me. its not remove number, and just focus on '.' and ',' but the code is ugly

Comment: Yh it's using `re` so it's bound to be pretty ugly. But this code is more understandable and efficient than the previous one. You can sort it using the code in the below code cells.

Answer (score 0):

using `sort` function and providing the key to on basic of which you need to sort , you can sort data

```
>>> productlinks = ['google.com', 'tes.com', 'lol.com']
>>> name = ['google', 'tes', 'lol']
>>> prices = ['$ 125', '$ 123','$ 135']
>>> 
>>> l = list(zip(productlinks, name, prices))
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[2].split()[-1]))
>>> 
>>> l
[('tes.com', 'tes', '$ 123'), ('google.com', 'google', '$ 125'), ('lol.com', 'lol', '$ 135')]
```

Comment: This is what works for me, but actually my prices is look like this: ["$ 13.000,00", "$ 12.000,00", $ 1.000,00"] and because of that there is errorValueError: could not convert string to float.

Comment: i have also splited the prices so it look like 123.000 but when i convert it to int, error occured " invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Comment: use `float` or `double`

Comment: cannot use float or double, because there is ',' and '.' in the string. so it return error.