# sort array based on sorting of a different array

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have 2 arrays:

```
firstArr = ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Chicken Soup", "French Fries"]
secondArr = [8, 6, 6, 9]
```

now I sort the second Array like this:

```
secondArr = [9, 8, 6, 6]
```

I then want the first Array to follow this new order:

```
firstArr = ["French Fries", "Pizza", "Chicken Soup", "Pasta"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So the first and second list have some relationship. Maybe you can try making a list of tuples `[("Pizza", 8),..., ("French Fries", 9)]`, and sort it from the second element of each value (tuple)! [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695139/sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-2nd-item-integer-value) is in python but I hope you get the idea!

Comment: How do you determine the sort order on items with the same weighting value? It's alphabetical in your example, but there's not really enough data to determine whether that's the rule or just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int temp = 0;
String temp1 = "";
for(int i=0; i< secondArr.size(); i++) {
   for(int j=i+1; j<secondArr.size(); j++) {
      if(secondArr[i] < secondArr[j]) {
         temp = secondArr[i];
         secondArr[i] = secondArr[j];
         secondArr[j] = temp;
         // To swap the second array if first is swapped on the same index
         temp1 = firstArr[i];
         firstArr[i] = firstArr[j];
         firstArr[j] = temp1; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I edited the question and added the code in cfml, too, if someone else needs it as cfml.

Comment: The question is for CFML... this is not CFML.

Comment: This isn't CFML. Why is this an accepted answer when it can't run as CFML?

Answer (score 2):

Probably like this:

```
items = ["Pizza", "Pasta", "Chicken Soup", "French Fries"]
weighting = [8, 6, 6, 9]

orderedItems = items
    .reduce(
        (weightedItems, v, i) => weightedItems.append({item=v, weight=weighting[i]}),
        []
    )
    .sort((e1, e2) => e2.weight == e1.weight ? compare(e1.item, e2.item) : sgn(e2.weight - e1.weight))
    .map((v)=>v.item)

writeDump(orderedItems)
```

- Merge the two arrays into one of item / weighting pairs.
- Sort that (primarily by weighting descending, then alpha where the weightings are equal).
- Return just the item names.

https://trycf.com/gist/e18db87198924030fca231b6b10e4f88/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: Upvoted this answer because its cfml and should be the accepted one.